# rjava and java issue with r on mac os mojave issue

Tags: r, rjava

I recently updated to the latest R version and Mojave.  I can't get Rjava to work anymore.  I tried reading the many topics on this, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong...

```
Loading required package: rJava
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded
```

enter this into terminal...

```
 /usr/libexec/java_home -V

Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    10.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 10.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_171, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

When I run

```
 sudo R CMD javareconf



Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 10.0.1
Java home path   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar
System Java on macOS

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers
detected JNI linker flags : -framework JavaVM
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I/anaconda3/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/anaconda3/include   -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
conftest.c:1:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
#include <jni.h>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [conftest.o] Error 1
Unable to compile a JNI program, ignoring this though as you may not want to compile anything here
.. this is an Anaconda Distribution and conda-forge customization whereby env activation causes us
.. to call R CMD javareconf in order to dynamically detect a JDK that may be in that env. The fact
.. that we prohibit setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH is also somewhat responsible for us needing to do this
.. because ${R_HOME}/etc/ldpaths is the normal way that R dynamically finds shared libraries. This
.. is what would, in upstream R, set LD_LIBRARY_PATH. AD cannot set this as it causes all sorts of
.. issues with DT_RUNPATH / DT_RPATH on various distributions.


JAVA_HOME        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
Java library path: 
JNI cpp flags    : -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers
JNI linker flags : -framework JavaVM
Updating Java configuration in /anaconda3/lib/R
Done.
```

Can someone tell me what I have to do?  I'm sure this has been repeated many times and is obvious but I cant figure it out or do it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jumping between Mac OS versions, Java versions and rJava releases might be a struggle.

Take a look here for quite comprehensive list of steps you might need to take:

http://www.owsiak.org/r-3-4-rjava-macos-and-even-more-mess/

It might be you need to recompile rJava from sources to get it working in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

reposting the quickest and most effective from https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2750

`sudo ln -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib`